# Zabbix Server do not resolve NetBios name in "DNS Name" when adding host

Tags: dns, zabbix, netbios

There is a problem confused me, I searched on Google but no result:

Most of my clients said that they are Windows, We have Microsoft AD. And DHCP, DNS servers are Windows Servers.

As you know non-domain joining windows client do not register on DNS, so windows use NetBios to resolve these clients.

I install samba-winbind on Zabbix Server and add

```
"wins" in /etc/nsswitch.conf : --> hosts:   files wins dns
```

So that Linux can use NetBios to resolve Windows Hostname, and I can get the response when pinging these clients.

**Problem:**

When I add the host to Zabbix Server, I fill in DNS name with the NetBIOS name. But Zabbix can't resolve.

I can Ping NetBios name in Linux, But Zabbix Server cannot resolve it when adding the host. What should I do to make Zabbix server resolve NetBIOS name, Thanks...

Comment: Are you trying to use active or passive Zabbix items? Which version of Zabbix? Did you restart Zabbix server after making name lookup changes?

Comment: @Richlv I am using Zabbix 3.4.7 , passive Zabbix items, I just tried to restart zabbix-server service, It works....thank you for your answer sincerely

Comment: Thank you for the followup, adding that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While daemons follow [`resolv.conf`](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/introduction/whatsnew343#daemon_improvements) changes in recent Zabbix versions, other name lookup file changes might require daemon restart. Please restart Zabbix server.